# MDX YTD Not working

Tags: ssas

What am I doing wrong??? Cannot get YTD working.

RUNNING:

```
With
MEMBER [measures].[YTDFees] AS
Aggregate (YTD([Date Dim].Year.CurrentMember),[Measures].[Fees])

SELECT {[Measures].[Fees],
    [Measures].[YTDFees]
    } ON COLUMNS,
{[DATE Dim].[Year].Children*[Date Dim].[Month].children }  ON ROWS
FROM [CheckCashingView]
```

GETTING:
        Fees            YTDFees

2013    1   6230939.22  6230939.22

2013    2   7856979.01  7856979.01

2013    3   7058780.18  7058780.18

2013    4   6144556.08  6144556.08

2013    5   6704988.58  6704988.58

2013    6   6298429.00  6298429.00

Comment: Please describe at least what output you're expecting and what database server environment you're working with. Use a better title. Stackoverflow contributors love clear question.

Comment: I think that based on the info give we can assume that the expected output is a running total for each year and that the server used is Analysis Services.

Comment: Do you have a user hierarchy in the `Date Dim` dimension that contains the hierarchy of years, months, and whatever types of times you have?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't mark your time dimension as a "Time" dimension in the SSAS option. Go to the SSAS Solution Explorer, select your Time dimension and open this dimension. Select the name of your Time dimension in the Attributes section make sure that in the dimension properties there is a "Time" in the Type properties.